# Open Popup with delay when clicking cell

Tags: wpf, popup, wpfdatagrid

I want to show a popup with delay 2 seconds always when any cell of a column is selected and the cursor stays longer than 2 seconds. I could implement that with timers and eventhandlers but I think,I can also achieve that with storyboards. I try to do that so:

```
<Window x:Class="Wpfpopupstoryboard.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ShowPopup">
        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LockPopup" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Popup.IsOpen)">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="True" />
        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="HidePopup" Storyboard.TargetName="LockPopup" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Popup.IsOpen)">
        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1" Value="False" />
        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <DataGrid Name="MyGrid" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Border x:Name="border"
                            BorderThickness="2"
                            BorderBrush="Silver">
                                    <ContentPresenter Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{Binding}"/>

                                </Border>
                                <Popup x:Name="LockPopup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyContentPresenter}" Placement="Bottom"  DataContext="{Binding}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="This is a popup" Background="White" Foreground="Black" />
                                </Popup>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowPopup}"/>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.MouseLeave">
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HidePopup}"/>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="column" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <sys:String>item 1</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 2</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 3</sys:String>
        <sys:String>item 4</sys:String>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

What is wrong? Can somebody help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using `RemoveStoryboard` action, you need just 1 Storyboard (to show the popup). Also the right event to trigger the Storyboard here is `Selected` instead of `StackPanel.MouseLeftButtonDown`:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Selected">
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowPopup}" Name="bg"/>
   </EventTrigger>
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowPopup}" Name="bg2"/>
   </EventTrigger>
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
      <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="bg"/>
   </EventTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

You can delete the `HidePopup` Storyboard, because we don't need it with the code above.

In fact you can also use `StackPanel.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`, somehow the `StackPanel.MouseLeftButtonDown` is suppressed (while bubbling up from the inner elements). However it's just a bit explanation about why it's not working at first. Using the `Selected` event is the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

`MouseLeftButtonDown` event have a `Direct` Routing strategy (see [UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown Event (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown(v=vs.110).aspx)).

So it will not bubble to your `ContentTemplate`.

You need to set the event trigger on your `StackPanel` directly.